# Sequence with a fixed last element Notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I was trying to write a sequence of two different elements (that always appear in order) with a fixed last element, for an example: $A_1, B_1, A_2, B_2, A_3, B_3, A_4$. I'm not sure which would be the best way to explain and represent this situation.

The best that I reached was: $\Gamma = \langle (A_{i},B_{i})_{i=1}^{n},A_{n+1} \rangle$. But I'm not sure if this notation is correct because it is actually a sequence of ordered pairs with a last element (that is not an ordered pair).

So, I'm asking you, is it a valid way to represent what I want? If not, which would be the best way to write that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can safely go with something simple:
$$A_1, B_1, A_2, B_2, \dotsc, A_n, B_n, A_{n+1}.$$

Comment: Hum, it makes sense. Why simplify when we can complicate :D. 

My only doubt is, with this notation, could I have a sequence with only 3 elements? A1,B1,A2? Or since I have the n>1 I would need at least 5 elements?

Comment: @Andre, you could clarify with "for $n\ge 1$" or something. Mathematical notation doesn't necessarily stand on its own.

Comment: Sure. Let's say, if I define the sequence as $A_1,B_1,...,A_n,B_n,A_{n+1}$, $n$ will need to be greater than one, naturally. 

What I'm asking is if with this definition the sequence $A_1,B_1,A_2$ would be valid (because in this case I would not have any possible element as $A_n$ or $B_n$).

Comment: @Andre, I understand your concern. On the other hand, using *too few* terms can be confusing in some cases. If you explicitly set the lower bound for $n$ that you want, I think whoever reads it will understand that if $n=1$ then the $A_2$ and $B_2$ terms will be dropped. In fact, if you were to write "for $n\ge 0$", then they would understand that if $n=0$ then the sequence will have *no* terms.

Comment: First, thanks for your help. My concern actually is with the $A_n$ and $B_n$ terms that I need to keep in the definition. If I put "for $n \geq 0$" then a sequence $A_1,B_2,A_0,B_0,A_1$ would be valid. But I don't see a way to create a definition that could accept the $A_1,B_1,A_2$ sequence (since I can have a sequence with only 3 elements) and also be generic for other cases. Maybe $\langle A_i,B_i,A_{n+1} \rangle_{i=1}^{n}$ ?

Comment: @Andre, mathematical notation in real life isn't as rigid as you seem to think. Unless you explicitly mention that the sequence $A_1,B_2,A_0,B_0,A_1$ is valid, no one will think that's what you meant. Yes, you *can* come up with an excruciatingly formal way to express yourself to remove almost all possible ambiguities, but you will end up with something so long and confusing that it will be very hard to understand. Don't worry; be happy. Math is a house of cards anyway, so just keep on building!

Comment: That's interesting and new to me. I'm not a mathematician, so all the few things that I heard about the notations, definitions and "writing math" were about how they need to be precise and exact representations to avoid future problems (and continues on how ambiguities would destroy the world :D).

Comment: @Andre, if you are interested in extreme formality, look into fields like formal logic, type theory, model theory, and axiomatic set theory. These fields use informal language to talk about formal languages. Check out Bernays's "class existence theorem", which shows how statements in first-order logic can be broken down into tiny little pieces suitable for a finite axiomatization of set theory.